# How to add custom field date-time in ddm structure?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-aui, liferay-velocity

Currently we can add only date in the structure. I want to add time as well. I had tried below link and created simple custom field.                                                  https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/57064529

Now I want to create custom field date and time in DDM structure.

[image: Currently we can add only date in the structure]

Comment: It won't help to cross post, if you don't explain what the problem is. What is wrong with the post you have linked to?

Comment: Post content how to display simple customfield I want to create special field name date and time. Currently liferay have inbuilt date field in ddm structure I want to add time as well. In 6.1 we had manage with help of below article  https://liferaycms.wordpress.com/2011/01/15/add-new-structure-field/                                                                                                Now everything changed. In 6.2 liferay used dynamic data mapping Thanks

Comment: I won't create the whole hook for you, so why don't you try the steps in the link from your original post? If you did, what was wrong with it? And please try to edit your question if you have anything to add...